# Detect when finger is dragged inside object (iOS touch)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I know I can use `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` in order to tell when I have touched a button dragged my touch outside its bounds and then re-entered those bounds. However I was wondering would it be possible to touch the screen, not on a button, and detect when I have dragged over/inside that button?

Also could someone tell me the difference between `UIControlEventTouchDragExit`  `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You would have to observe touch events on the button's superview and whenever the user's fingers move, call `hitTest:withEvent:` to check whether the touch coordinates lie on top of the button.
2. I believe the difference between `UIControlEventTouchDragExit` and `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside` is this: when the finger moves from inside the control to the outside, `UIControlEventTouchDragExit` fires once. Then, as long as the finger remains outside, `UIControlEventTouchDragOutside` fires on each move. But you should test this yourself.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. Thanks.